# ScreenGrid on python manim as a not defined name

Tags: python, manim

My script is as follows:

```py
from manimlib.imports import *

class cena(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        rede = ScreenGrid()
        texto = TextMobject('Ana')
        self.add(texto,rede)
        self.wait(2)
```

I keep getting the following error:

> "NameError: name 'ScreenGrid' is not defined"

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 1):

You must pay more attention to the details of the video, at minute [5:44](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gIvQsqXy5os&t=5m44s) I specify that you must copy the Grid and ScreenGrid classes in order to be used. That is, the complete file must be:

```py
from manimlib.imports import *


class Grid(VGroup):
    CONFIG = {
        "height": 6.0,
        "width": 6.0,
    }

    def __init__(self, rows, columns, **kwargs):
        digest_config(self, kwargs, locals())
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        x_step = self.width / self.columns
        y_step = self.height / self.rows

        for x in np.arange(0, self.width + x_step, x_step):
            self.add(Line(
                [x - self.width / 2., -self.height / 2., 0],
                [x - self.width / 2., self.height / 2., 0],
            ))
        for y in np.arange(0, self.height + y_step, y_step):
            self.add(Line(
                [-self.width / 2., y - self.height / 2., 0],
                [self.width / 2., y - self.height / 2., 0]
            ))


class ScreenGrid(VGroup):
    CONFIG = {
        "rows": 8,
        "columns": 14,
        "height": FRAME_Y_RADIUS * 2,
        "width": 14,
        "grid_stroke": 0.5,
        "grid_color": WHITE,
        "axis_color": RED,
        "axis_stroke": 2,
        "labels_scale": 0.25,
        "labels_buff": 0,
        "number_decimals": 2
    }

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        rows = self.rows
        columns = self.columns
        grid = Grid(width=self.width, height=self.height, rows=rows, columns=columns)
        grid.set_stroke(self.grid_color, self.grid_stroke)

        vector_ii = ORIGIN + np.array((- self.width / 2, - self.height / 2, 0))
        vector_si = ORIGIN + np.array((- self.width / 2, self.height / 2, 0))
        vector_sd = ORIGIN + np.array((self.width / 2, self.height / 2, 0))

        axes_x = Line(LEFT * self.width / 2, RIGHT * self.width / 2)
        axes_y = Line(DOWN * self.height / 2, UP * self.height / 2)

        axes = VGroup(axes_x, axes_y).set_stroke(self.axis_color, self.axis_stroke)

        divisions_x = self.width / columns
        divisions_y = self.height / rows

        directions_buff_x = [UP, DOWN]
        directions_buff_y = [RIGHT, LEFT]
        dd_buff = [directions_buff_x, directions_buff_y]
        vectors_init_x = [vector_ii, vector_si]
        vectors_init_y = [vector_si, vector_sd]
        vectors_init = [vectors_init_x, vectors_init_y]
        divisions = [divisions_x, divisions_y]
        orientations = [RIGHT, DOWN]
        labels = VGroup()
        set_changes = zip([columns, rows], divisions, orientations, [0, 1], vectors_init, dd_buff)
        for c_and_r, division, orientation, coord, vi_c, d_buff in set_changes:
            for i in range(1, c_and_r):
                for v_i, directions_buff in zip(vi_c, d_buff):
                    ubication = v_i + orientation * division * i
                    coord_point = round(ubication[coord], self.number_decimals)
                    label = Text(f"{coord_point}",font="Arial",stroke_width=0).scale(self.labels_scale)
                    label.next_to(ubication, directions_buff, buff=self.labels_buff)
                    labels.add(label)

        self.add(grid, axes, labels)


class cena(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        rede = ScreenGrid()
        texto = TextMobject('Ana')
        self.add(texto,rede)
        self.wait(2)
```

**Questions like this will be ignored in the future.**

Comment: Thank you very much. I watched the video a couple times, but totally lost it. I think the quarantine is not going well on my attention. By the way, congratulations on your tutorial. Its very helpful.